# Whats the "height" version of, elongate?

Tags: meaning, antonyms

I figured **elongate** would just mean to "make longer," and would be orientation/dimension dependent.  I Googled it just to double check, and a lot of definitions refer to "longer in relation to the width."

What is the term used to mean longer in height?  Searching for antonyms for elongate wasn't promising.  Could height and width possibly be transposed in the definition?

Comment: Never heard of *heighten*?

Comment: How about *embiggen*? Works in all contexts and dimensions.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I haven't heard of widthen.

Comment: @Robusto is this a valid English word?

Comment: It's in Wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen). But mainly I was making a joke. The word comes from the TV comedy *The Simpsons*.

Comment: @RegDwight I've rarely if ever heard 'heighten' used literally. Usually, 'raise' or 'grow' (or the more general 'extend') work and seem to be preferred.

Comment: Why don't you just tell the guy to lie down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'elongate' the verb *does* mean 'make longer'

What you have found is the adjective. It is similar in form to oblate and prolate (and indeed accurate).

Note that the definitions I have found with a quick online dictionary search seem to favour 'long in proportion to width' or similar, e.g.

> elongate - having a ​shape that is much ​longer than it is ​wide:
>
> **[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elongate)**

Therefore, if I understand you correctly, you can use it for your purposes.